# Making a particular ViewController as frontViewController in SWRevealViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, swrevealviewcontroller

I am doing a project in which I have implemented `**SWRevealViewController**` to achieve slide-out menu & now I have got the following scenario -

***I already have a view controller in my story board whose class is set to `SWRevealViewController` but that is not inter connected to my `CreateNotificationVC` by any means***

1)**CreateNotificationVC** embedded in a navigation controller **CreateNotificationNVC**.

2)I have a TableViewController which I want to be my rearVC.

**storyBoardID -**

CreateNotificationNVC - "createNtfctnNVC"
rearTableViewController - "rearTVC"

**Scenario -**

I want **CreateNotificationVC** to act as **frontViewController** when user moves to this VC & implement all type of functionalities of SWRevealViewController.

**Code Till Now-**

In my CreateNotificationVC -

```
let revealView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RevealVC") as! SWRevealViewController //Here I am instantiating my already present RevealViewController in storyboard


        let nvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("createNtfctnNVC") as! createNtfctnNVC//createNtfctnNVC is the storyBoardId of Nav Controller in which CreateNotificationVC is embedded


    let rvc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("rearTVC") as! SlideMenuTVC//Here I am instantiating the TblViewCntrllr which acts as rearVC of my already present RevealViewController

        revealView.setFrontViewController(nvc, animated: true)
        revealView.pushFrontViewController(nvc, animated: true)
        revealView.setRearViewController(rvc, animated: true)

        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(revealView.panGestureRecognizer())
```

**Problem -** Swiping or toggling from any button in CreateNotificationVC does not result in the show up of slide menu.

Please help about this as not much works for this 3rd Party is found in swift.

[image]

Comment: can you show your storyboard

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Ya i have just updated my question. Please have a look.

Comment: now tell bro , which vc you want to set

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik The createNotificationVC in the bottom right corner embedded in createNotificationVC and the rest is in my qstn. All details.

Comment: but SWL working in custom segue , but on that class there is no more NSobject class

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik So what are you suggesting to do to achieve what I want?

Comment: you have already implemeneted the swl in your app

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Ya I have implemented once and now my createNotificationVC has to show the slide menu but its not connected with the RevealViewController in storyboard . As you can see in the story board.

Comment: try once and create the additional one for concept, but i am not sure it is work or not

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik No I have did several times but its not possible by any means?

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Please suggest something about this issue. I have seen lot many answers of yours regarding this btfl 3rd prty. Please help to resolve this issue.

Comment: tanx a lot bro, I worked on SWL in more than 9 projects, but your question is very complicated , but we can do at the same time it will take time bro , is this my no 9790811202, if you need a help I surely support you

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/551 - Thanks for all your effort.you can check this link if you have time & see the suggestion over there.